# Remove string after a predefined string from a nested list of dictionaries with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":["a","b2","keep this exemple from work_text_reviews_count of 450"],
    },
    {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":[],
    }
]
```

How can i Remove string from predefined string with pandas without changing the structure.

**the predefined string** = "from work_text_reviews_count of"

the text that i want to remove **"from work_text_reviews_count of 450"**

The expected output:

```
[
    {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":["a","b2","keep this exemple"],
    },
    {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":[],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have much choice here but to loop.

###### updated question:

```
pat = " from work_text_reviews_count of"
df['key3'] = [[x.split(pat)[0] for x in l] for l in df['key3']]
```

output:

```
     key1 key2                        key3
0  value1    2  [a, b2, keep this exemple]
1  value1    2                          []
```

###### older example

To update the data in place:

```
for l in df['details']:
    for d in l:
        if "average_rating" in d:
            d["average_rating"] = d["average_rating"].split()[0]
```

output:

```
    name                                                               details
0  Book1   [{'id': 30278752, 'isbn': ' 1594634025', 'average_rating': '3.92'}]
1  Book2  [{'id': 34006942, 'isbn': '  1501173219', 'average_rating': '4.33'}]
```

Comment: Sorry i putted a wrong example :/ i updated my post

Comment: @Prestige this is still the same logic, you need to loop

Comment: But i cannot split() with position 0 (Cause i have multiple lines and i don't know i which position the the predefined string will be

Comment: you can split on `'from work_text_reviews_count of'` ;) or use a regex if more complex

Comment: @Prestige see update example